# Why is change cipher spec an independent protocol content type and not part of Handshake Messages?

Tags: tls

RFC 2246 says:

> To help avoid pipeline stalls, ChangeCipherSpec is an independent TLS
>   Protocol content type, and is not actually a TLS handshake message.

What pipeline stalss is being spoken about here?  Why didn't the creators of TLS make Change Cipher Spec a part of Handshake Message itself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

SSL uses *messages* which are encoded over *records*. Encryption is done on a per record basis. However, several messages of the same type (e.g. handshake messages) can be crammed together in the same record. Since the Change Cipher Spec message modifies encryption settings, a new record should begin immediately afterwards, so that the new settings are immediately applied (in particular, it is crucial for security that the Finished message uses the new encryption and MAC).

Using a specific record type for Change Cipher Spec is a way to enforce this property. An SSL/TLS implementation cannot help but begin a new record for the Finished message, since it uses a record type distinct from that of the Change Cipher Spec message. Such a specific record type *could* be avoided if all SSL/TLS implementations were disciplined enough to begin a new record where they need, and also to verify that the peer *also* began a new record. It is safer and more robust to make it unavoidable through the record type.

Comment: so this is to prevent bad implementations or a design problem? if I understand correctly: without the changecipherspec, tls by design would cram the finished message with client key exchange and other client messages?

Comment: The ChangeCipherSpec message is mostly historical. One could design a protocol which looks like SSL/TLS but without that specific message, and it would work because when a party sends a ChangeCipherSpec, the peer expects it (and will complain if the message is not received). From a protocol point of view, the message is redundant. However, presence of that message makes it more difficult for bad implementers to make a bad implementation in that respect.

Comment: what is a record and record type?